# Random variable is not $\mathcal{A}$-measurable

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to understand what's going on here, this is notes from a lecture and my additions in italic:

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and an integrable random $X$ (i.e, $\mathbb{E}[|X|]< \infty $).

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. *This simply implies that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$?*
We typically assume that $X$ is not $\mathcal{A}$-measurable.

*What does it mean that a random variable is/is not $\mathcal{A}$-measurable?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of what's given is an (integrable) random variable $X$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. This means two things, one that $X$ is a measurable function with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$, and two that $\int |X|\,d\mathbb P < \infty$. The second condition expresses that $X$ is integrable. It's the first thing that your question is really about.

Saying that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal F$ means that for any Borel set $B\subset \mathbb R$, the event $\{X\in B\}:=\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in B\}$ is a member of $\mathcal F$. If we also have a sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal F$, it may not be the case that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal A$. This is because the events of the form $\{X\in B\}$ are only assumed to be members of $\mathcal F$, and $\mathcal A$ *as a subset* of $\mathcal F$, may not contain all (or some) of the events $\{X\in B\}$. *(Notice that the probability measure $\mathbb P$ does not factor into this discussion.)*

As a simple example of this, say our sample space is $\Omega=\{1,\dots,6\}^2$, all the outcomes of two dice rolls, and $\mathcal F$ is the power set of $\Omega$. Let $X$ be the random variable which is $1$ if we roll $(1,1)$, and $0$ otherwise. Then $X$ *is* measurable with respect to the sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal A_1 = \{\emptyset,\Omega,\{(1,1)\},\Omega\setminus\{(1,1)\}\}$, but it is *not* measurable with respect to the trivial sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal A_2 = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, because for instance the event $\{X = 1\} = \{(1,1)\}$ is not a member of $\mathcal A_2$.

Answer (score 0):

A random variable $X$ is a measurable function $X:(E,F,P) \rightarrow Y$ where $E$ is a measure space and $Y$ is a topological space if for every open set $U$ in $Y$ the inverse image $V=X^{-1}(U)\implies V\in F$.